# Google search in an iOS app

Tags: ios, json, api, search

Developing a browser here and wanted to add "live search" to the address field like most browsers have today. Started out by using Google's

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=QUERY

But then it turns out that's deprecated and has a limit on the number of searches.

So I found the new Custom Search, turned it on, created an API key matching my app's bundle identifier, and tried doing:

> https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MYKEY&q=QUERY

But with that I just get an error back saying "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."

I went back to the developer console and checked, and custom search IS turned on. If I try changing the key in the app I get a completely different error, same if I change the bundle identifier on both sides. So it is validating the key and my app.

Someone mentioned that you need to use cx= and pass in the identifier to your custom search, but to make a custom search you need to specify a URL, and I'm trying to search the entire web.

So is the new API just for searching specific sites, is there no longer any way to get regular search results out of Google's API? Or am I missing something else here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use google custom search API that you mentioned above.

And your way which using 'cx=' and 'key=' is okey.

This is the answer for "I'm trying to search the entire web".

1. Go to your CSE.
2. Check out 'Basics' tab is selected.
3. Now, you can see 'Sites to search' field and there are some sites.

   - sites should be added when you make new CSE.
4. First, you should delete all site you added.
5. Second, you choose "Search the entire web but emphasize include sites".

That's it!
If you done above steps, you can search from entire web.

But, each CSE is limited 100 times per day.